# Swift Closures [unowned singleton]

Tags: swift, memory-management, closures

Having an issue with a recursive memory leak in Swift, where a singleton is being called inside the closure of another singleton.

```
NetworkManager.sharedInstance.doThingWithCompletion(urlString) { [unowned self] (complete) -> Void in

       if complete == true {

           if self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count > 0 {

               CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.save(self.dictionary, completion: { (complete) -> Void in

            })
        }
    }
}
```

How do I add the singleton as unowned to the capture list? Should I even be doing that??

***EDIT***

Spotted by Quantaliinuxite, Core Data Manager had an issue... absolutely no problem with this sort of architecture.

```
static let sharedInstance = BFSCoreDataManager()

deinit {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

// MARK: - Saving

func observeContext(context:NSManagedObjectContext) {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector:"mergeChangesFromNotification:",
        name: NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification,
        object: nil) // ** PROBLEM WAS HERE **
}

func mergeChangesFromNotification(notification:NSNotification) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        self.managedObjectContext.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly do we define singletons as "leaked"? By their nature they are never released...

Comment: Yeah good point.. To define it, calling the inner singleton method spirals the memory out exponentially until crash. Even if the method is empty.

Comment: and the CDM singleton doesnt call your NetworkManager at any point? Something you could do for debugging is look at the stack trace and see what the whole recursive shenanigan  is about.

Comment: Just for posterity CDM is always downwind of NetworkManager.

Comment: Could you post the stack trace? Does the problem go away if you don't nest the loops? Software doesn't just crash, and nesting singletons calls isn't necessarily bad practice. Use Instruments to help you track down the bug. EDIT: Try replacing unwoned with weak. Another guess: fetchedResultsController is a lazy var. Do you reference self in the initialization closure?

Comment: Something is definitely wrong with my Core Data Manager singleton. I get the same issue when savingContext right before popping a viewcontroller.

Comment: Please post the code for your Core Data Manager class

Comment: Done. The problem also arises when I save a note right before popping a view controller. Only on iOS 8.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107330/discussion-between-quantaliinuxite-and-magoo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be worth looking at how you define your singleton. As a general rule I do something like this:

```
class MySingleton {
    static let sharedInstance = MySingleton() //The singleton
}
```

This leaves a clean stack trace and is confusion free. For reference: 
http://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton

**EDIT:**

It appears the bug is in the `BFSCoreDataManager` class.
in `observerContext:`, you forget to listen to the context. The function should be:

```
func observeContext(context:NSManagedObjectContext) {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector:"mergeChangesFromNotification:",
        name: NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification,
        object: context) //context instead of nil
}
```

Comment: Should be static let if I'm pedantic.

Comment: Again for posterity both are defined in this way.

Comment: Thanks again Quantaliinuxite

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will solve the memory management problem, but the way to include the singleton in the capture list is like this:

```
NetworkManager.sharedInstance.doThingWithCompletion(urlString) { 
    [unowned self, unowned dataManager = CoreDataManager.sharedInstance] (complete) -> Void in

    if complete {

        if self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count > 0 {

            dataManager.save(self.dictionary, completion: { (complete) -> Void in

            })
        }
    }
}
```

Note also that when checking a `Bool` value, you don't need to compare it to `true`. `if complete == true { ... }` can be shortened to `if complete { ... }`

Comment: OK that's great... I'll take a look at adding that and see how I get on.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's handy to know